# Python autodetect file as csv or json and read it

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Objective:**

1. Python 3 Function should be able to read both `json` or `csv` file and must return json
2. AutoDetect format , i am using try catch trick with `return json.load(fileObject)`
3. Full strict function with try catch statement

**ISSUE:**
It works fine with `json` file given as input but for `csv` it displays *empty array*

Any Better approach ??

**CSV File:**

```
Alpha,Beta,Gamma
1,2,3
```

**JSON File:**

```
[
  {
    "Alpha": 1,
    "Beta": 2,
    "Gamma": 3
  }
]
```

**CODE:**

```
import csv
import json

def read_input_File(file_path):
    try:
        fileObject = open(file_path, 'rU')
        # check if it is json
        try:
            return json.load(fileObject)
        except:
            # it is csv then
            reader = csv.DictReader(fileObject)
            # Parse the CSV into JSON
            out = json.dumps([row for row in reader])
            return out
    except IOError as e:
        raise SystemExit("I/O error(%s): %s", e.errno, e.strerror)

    finally:
        fileObject.close()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing that the `json.load()` call has consumed the file. Try `fileObject.seek(0)` before the `csv.DictReader()` call perhaps?

Comment: thankx.it works .
any improvement in try ctach ?can i avoid nested try ctach ?

Comment: If you have some way of knowing what the file is without looking at the content, then you can to that - see Michelangelo Conserva's answer. Otherwise, this is probably as good as you're going to get. "Easier to ask forgiveness" (as opposed to "look before you leap") is pretty idiomatic in Python - see [Idiomatic Python: EAFP versus LBYL](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/idiomatic-python-eafp-versus-lbyl/).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think using try catch block is necessary. For sake of readability I'd use an if else statement.

```
import json
import csv

def read_input_File(file_path):
    if file_path.endswith(".json"): return json.load(open(file_path,"r"))    
    elif file_path.endswith(".csv"): return json.dumps(list(csv.DictReader(open("prova.csv"))))
    else: raise ValueError("The file is not json nor cvs")
```

Comment: I think `if file_path.endswith(".json")` is cleaner

Comment: safer will be `file_path.lower().endswith(".json")` - there might be files with upper cased extensions.